# allure-playwright (or general allure) style customisation

Tags: playwright, allure

In my current project I use allure-playwright to generate the reports.  I get allure-playwright from npm like any other normal node package.

However, is there any way to customise the styling of the report?  I've looked and all answers are for the Java version of allure and where allure is built locally (which I am not doing) - so am I stuck with the default styling?